# Conditional row summing inside of group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some trouble with summing of rows in my df, I want to sum `BAD` and `UGLY` rows inside of each group if they exist!

```
group = c(seq(1,1.4,0.2),rep(seq(1.6,2,0.2),c(3,3,2)))
clas=c(rep("BAD",3),rep(c("BAD","GOOD","UGLY"),2),rep(c("BAD","GOOD"),1))
n=c(rep(1000,3),96,180,715,190,184,26,124,874)
df <- data.frame(group,clas,n)

> df
#   group clas    n
#1    1.0  BAD 1000
#2    1.2  BAD 1000
#3    1.4  BAD 1000
#4    1.6  BAD   96
#5    1.6 GOOD  180
#6    1.6 UGLY  715
#7    1.8  BAD  190
#8    1.8 GOOD  184
#9    1.8 UGLY   26
#10   2.0  BAD  124
#11   2.0 GOOD  874
```

I tried this but of course it didnt work because of my poor logic!

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate(sum = ifelse(all(clas=="BAD"),n,ifelse(with(clas=="BAD"&clas=="UGLY"),n["BAD"]+n["UGLY"],"NA")))
```

> Error: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'logical'

The expected output if the code can be fixed,

```
> df
    #   group clas    n  sum
    #1    1.0  BAD 1000   1000
    #2    1.2  BAD 1000   1000
    #3    1.4  BAD 1000   1000
    #4    1.6  BAD   96    811
    #5    1.6 GOOD  180    811
    #6    1.6 UGLY  715    811
    #7    1.8  BAD  190    216
    #8    1.8 GOOD  184    216 
    #9    1.8 UGLY   26    216
    #10   2.0  BAD  124    124
    #11   2.0 GOOD  874    124
```

thanks!

Comment: `df %>%  group_by(group) %>%   mutate(sum = sum(n)- sum(n[clas=="GOOD"]))` or `sum(n[clas=="BAD"|clas=="UGLY"])`

Comment: @zx8754 nope. not necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'group', get a logical index based on the 'BAD', 'UGLY' elements in 'clas' using `%in%`, subset the 'n' with this index, get the `sum` and assign (`:=`) it to a new column 'Sum'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  Sum := sum(n[as.character(clas) %chin% c("BAD", "UGLY")]), by = group]
df
#   group clas    n  Sum
#1:   1.0  BAD 1000 1000
#2:   1.2  BAD 1000 1000
#3:   1.4  BAD 1000 1000
#4:   1.6  BAD   96  811
#5:   1.6 GOOD  180  811
#6:   1.6 UGLY  715  811
#7:   1.8  BAD  190  216
#8:   1.8 GOOD  184  216
#9:   1.8 UGLY   26  216
#10:   2.0  BAD  124  124
#11:   2.0 GOOD  874  124
```

#### Benchmarks

On a 1e6 dataset, the benchmarks are

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(group = sample(1:1000, 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
         clas = sample(c("BAD", "GOOD", "UGLY"), 1e6, replace=TRUE),
         n = sample(100:1000, 1e6, replace=TRUE))


df2 <- copy(df1)

system.time(setDT(df1)[,  Sum := sum(n[as.character(clas) %chin% c("BAD", "UGLY")]), by = group])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.04    0.02    0.06 


system.time(merge(df2, aggregate(n~group, df2[!df2$clas == "GOOD", ], sum), by = "group", 
                                                suffixes = c("", "Sum")))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.00    0.16    5.17
```

If we increase the number of rows from 1e6 to 1e7

```
system.time(setDT(df1)[,  Sum := sum(n[as.character(clas) %chin% c("BAD", "UGLY")]), by = group])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.65    0.00    0.66 
system.time(merge(df2, aggregate(n~group, df2[!df2$clas == "GOOD", ], sum), by = "group", 
                                                suffixes = c("", "Sum")))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  58.00    1.58   59.78
```

Comment: thanks a lot for also `data.table` approach. I just wonder is `data.table` better than `dplyr`?

Comment: @Alexander The assign (`:=`) does it in place so it should be more efficient.

Comment: I see but still I find `data.table` hard to understand. Maybe in time I'll get used to it;)

Comment: maybe I can use combination of `dplyr` and `data.table`. since I always start with cleansing the data with `dplyr`  and do this kind of manipulation to the data. I wish to learn more about both. Do you have a blog or something?

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `base R` `aggregate` and `merge`.

We can `aggregate` `n` over `group` ignoring the `clas` `GOOD` and then `merge` them by `group` to original dataframe to get expected number of rows.

```
merge(df, aggregate(n~group, df[!df$clas == "GOOD", ], sum), by = "group", 
                                                   suffixes = c("", "Sum"))


#   group clas    n Sum
#1    1.0  BAD 1000 1000
#2    1.2  BAD 1000 1000
#3    1.4  BAD 1000 1000
#4    1.6  BAD   96  811
#5    1.6 GOOD  180  811
#6    1.6 UGLY  715  811
#7    1.8  BAD  190  216
#8    1.8 GOOD  184  216
#9    1.8 UGLY   26  216
#10   2.0  BAD  124  124
#11   2.0 GOOD  874  124
```